# Stop videos in PhotoSwipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

I'm using PhotoSwipe with a custom html5 video embed and it works fine.
But i'm having a problem with stopping video when the modal is closed or changes slide.

I have made this funktion to stop the video, but it only works when i click the close og slide buttons. Not when i use the keyboard to close or change slide.

```
$('.pswp__button--close, .pswp__button--arrow--left, .pswp__button--arrow--right').click(function() { 
    $("video").each(function () { this.pause() });
});
```

How do i hook into PhotoSwipes funktion and trigger the event?

```
$("video").each(function () { this.pause() });
```

This is my PhotoSwipe script:

```
    (function() {

    var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {

    // parse slide data (url, title, size ...) from DOM elements 
    // (children of gallerySelector)
    var parseThumbnailElements = function(el) {
        var thumbElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.all_gallery')),
            numNodes = thumbElements.length,
            items = [],
            figureEl,
            linkEl,
            size,
            item;

        for(var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {

            figureEl = thumbElements[i]; // <figure> element

            // include only element nodes 
            if(figureEl.nodeType !== 1) {
                continue;
            }

            linkEl = figureEl.children[0]; // <a> element

            // create slide object
              if ($(linkEl).data('type') == 'video') {
                item = {
                  html: $(linkEl).data('video')
                };
              } else {
                size = linkEl.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');
                item = {
                  src: linkEl.getAttribute('href'),
                  w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                  h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
                };
              }

            if(figureEl.children.length > 1) {
                // <figcaption> content
                item.title = figureEl.children[1].innerHTML; 
            }

            if(linkEl.children.length > 0) {
                // <img> thumbnail element, retrieving thumbnail url
                item.msrc = linkEl.children[0].getAttribute('src');
            } 

            item.el = figureEl; // save link to element for getThumbBoundsFn
            items.push(item);
        }

        return items;
    };

    // find nearest parent element
    var closest = function closest(el, fn) {
        return el && ( fn(el) ? el : closest(el.parentNode, fn) );
    };


    // triggers when user clicks on thumbnail
    var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

        var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;

        // find root element of slide
        var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
            return (el.tagName && el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'FIGURE');
        });

        if(!clickedListItem) {
            return;
        }

        // find index of clicked item by looping through all child nodes
        // alternatively, you may define index via data- attribute
        var clickedGallery = document.querySelectorAll('.nymf-gallery')[0], childNodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.all_gallery')),
            numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
            nodeIndex = 0,
            index;

        for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
            if(childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) { 
                continue; 
            }

            if(childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
                index = nodeIndex;
                break;
            }
            nodeIndex++;
        }

        if(index >= 0) {
            // open PhotoSwipe if valid index found
            openPhotoSwipe( index, clickedGallery );
        }
        return false;
    };

    var openPhotoSwipe = function(index, galleryElement, disableAnimation, fromURL) {
        var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0],
            gallery,
            options,
            items;

        items = parseThumbnailElements(galleryElement);

        // define options (if needed)
        options = {

            // define gallery index (for URL)
            galleryUID: galleryElement.getAttribute('data-pswp-uid'),

            getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
                // See Options -> getThumbBoundsFn section of documentation for more info
                var thumbnail = items[index].el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0], // find thumbnail
                    pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                    rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect(); 

                return {x:rect.left, y:rect.top + pageYScroll, w:rect.width};
            }

        };

        // PhotoSwipe opened from URL
        if(fromURL) {
            if(options.galleryPIDs) {
                // parse real index when custom PIDs are used 
                // http://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html#custom-pid-in-url
                for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                    if(items[j].pid == index) {
                        options.index = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // in URL indexes start from 1
                options.index = parseInt(index, 10) - 1;
            }
        } else {
            options.index = parseInt(index, 10);
        }

        // exit if index not found
        if( isNaN(options.index) ) {
            return;
        }

        options.showHideOpacity = 1000;
        options.showAnimationDuration = 1;
        options.hideAnimationDuration = 1;

        // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
        gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
        gallery.init();
    };

    // loop through all gallery elements and bind events
    var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll( gallerySelector );

    for(var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
        galleryElements[i].setAttribute('data-pswp-uid', i+1);
        galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
    }
   };
    initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.nymf-gallery');
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

After this:

```
//Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
gallery.init();
```

You ad:

```
gallery.listen('close', function() {
    $("video").each(function () { this.pause() });
});
gallery.listen('beforeChange', function() {
    $("video").each(function () { this.pause() });
});
```